# Reversing Linked List using pointers in C Coding Language

Tags: c, reverse, singly-linked-list

Attempting to reverse the linked list before printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct NODE {
    int value;
    struct NODE* prev;
    struct NODE* next;
};


struct NODE* addElement(struct NODE *tail, int val){

    struct NODE *n = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    n->value =val;
    n->prev=NULL;
    if(tail==NULL){
        return n;
    }
    struct NODE* c=tail;
    while(c!=NULL && c->prev!=NULL){
        c=c->prev;
    }
    c->prev=n;
    return tail;
    }

struct NODE* deleteEqualNodes(struct NODE *tail, int x){
    struct NODE *temp = tail, *prev;
    if (temp != NULL && temp->value == x) {
        tail = temp->prev;
        free(temp);
        temp = tail;
    }
  

    while (temp != NULL) {
        while (temp != NULL && temp->value != x) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
        if (temp == NULL)
            return tail;
        prev->prev = temp->prev;
        free(temp);
        temp = prev->prev;
    }
    return tail;
}

void printList(struct NODE *tail){
    int count=0;
    //if(tail == NULL) return;
    //tail->prev = tail;
    while(tail!=NULL){
        if(count==0){
            printf("%d ",tail->value);
            count=1;
        }
       else{
           printf(", %d ",tail->value);
       }
    tail = tail->prev;
    
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct NODE* tail=NULL;
    struct NODE* newList=NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int a;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        newList = addElement(newList, a);
    }
    int k;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    k = k + 1;
    tail = deleteEqualNodes(newList, k);
    printList(tail);
    
}
```

Input pointer 'n' size (ex. 9)

Input n integers (ex. 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3)

Input which node (index) should be removed (ex. 5)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Current Output (ex. " 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3")

**Desired** Output (ex. "3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1")

**important*** Removal must be done before reversal of the linked list

Comment: Code too big. Do this: 

Remove bits of your code, while testing.  Remove everything that is not relevant to the bug - find the smallest code example where your bug is still present, and you can't make your code smaller and still have the bug.  Doing so, your program may not make sense anymore.  Don't worry about that - your goal is to reproduce the bug. 

In the process of doing so, you will possibly figure out what your problem is.  If not, post the smallest example here.

It'scalled "SSCCE" - Smallest, self-contained, correct example.  "Correct" here means - producing the bug.

Comment: Why did you not debug your code? You could at least insert some `printf()` at relevant locations and print "interesting" values.

Comment: Since your question is about reversal, you should omit the part that deletes nodes. Provide only the minimal code to highlight your problem.